# Save specific incoming messages to the hard drive

Tags: vba, outlook

How to save specific incoming messages to the local hard drive programmatically
or 
How to save an outlook folder to a local hard drive programmatically

either or works for me

Comment: Google this: how to save outlook messages automatically to a file as they arrive

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to save emails is using  ***Outlook Rule + simple vba Script***

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Save_Example(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Temp\"

    If Item.Subject = "Hello" Then
        FileName = "Bla Bla" & ".msg"
        Item.SaveAs Path & FileName, olMsg
    End If

End Sub
```